# DateTime in UTC not converting to Local

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I'm receiving a `DateTime` response from API that's sets the timezone to UTC.

But when I try to convert the received data using `toLocal()` it doesn't convert.

my local time is **HKT**

here's my code.

```
    //TIME DIFFERENCE
  getNotificationDate(DateTime date) {
    date = date.toUtc();
    final convertedDate = date.toLocal();

    final dateNow = DateTime.now();
    print('TIMENOW: ' + dateNow.toString());
    print('TIMENOTIFC: ' + convertedDate.toString());
    final difference = dateNow.difference(convertedDate);
    print('DIFFERENCE: ' + difference.toString());
    return getDurationFormat(difference);
  }
```

**EDIT:**

`date` is the `DateTime` I'm receiving from the API. which is in UTC timezone.

I used `print('TIMEZONENAME: ' + date.timeZoneName;` and it automatically sets the timezone to **HKT**. that's why it does nothing when I try to use `date.toLocal()`

Comment: What do you mean that it "doesn't convert"? Is the result not in local time (e.g., according to `isUtc`)? Is the time for it not correct? What output did you *expect* for your example program?

Comment: for example, my current `local time` is **11:00 PM**. I'm now sending **11:00 PM** to the API. Now, my **11:00 PM** is being converted by the backend to `UTC` which would then become **3:08 pm** because the backend's `DateTime` is set to `UTC` by default. Now I will navigate to a page wherein I'm getting that `DateTime` that I just sent. I thought that by default, flutter would detect that `DateTime's` timezone but I was wrong. flutter automatically sets the incoming `DateTime` to my `Local` Timezone.

Comment: **P.S.** I'm not including my `local time` as a parameter when calling a `POST` request. it would simply be `created_at` at the backends side.

Comment: Dart `DateTime` only supports two time zones - UTC and "local". If you get an incoming time and you create a `DateTime` object for it, it will be in one of those two time zones. The incoming "time" is probably a string, so I assume you parse it. If that string contains, say, a `+02:00` time-zone marker then it is parsed as UTC by subtracting the time-zone offset from the parsed date. If it has no time-zone marker (no "+02" and no "Z") then it is interpreted as a local time.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't have `+02` or  `Z`. will there be a way to change that after I receive it?

Comment: If you get the string, you can add something to it, like "Z", but that will make it be interpreted as a UTC time, not the local-time of the sender. If you get the `DateTime` object, you probably have to create a new object from that, say by doing toString, adding "Z" and parsing it again. If you *know* the time zone of the server, say UTC+3, you can add `+03:00` after the string and get the UTC-time corresponding to that moment in time

Comment: Did you finally found something working ? I have same problem

Comment: @Gentle Can you please mark as an accepted answer so that we can save others time? :)

Answer (score 79):

Flutter gave us the easiest way to convert it.
You just need to pass **utc: true** while parsing your date.

```
var dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateUtc, true);
var dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
```

**Input**:

Assume my TimeZone : +05:30

UTC Date -> 2020-02-12 23:57:02.000

**Output**:

Local Date -> 2020-02-12 18:27:02.019660

Comment: Hi, this isn't working when I pass a date like this - 2020-08-15T05:01:31Z, which is a valid UTC date.

Comment: @Varundroid Have you tried with parsing with "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"?

Comment: @Varundroid like, var dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parse("2020-08-15T05:01:31Z", true);

Comment: This works well but DateFormat is from the intl package

Comment: Is there a way to add it at one place and make useable for all DateTime in the app?

Comment: @AhmadKhan In that case, you can create a dynamic function.

Comment: What will be string pattern for this '2022-01-01T00:00:00+00:00' ? I don't understand the last four 0 part..

Comment: @Md.Sulayman I assume that is the timezone. eg +05:30 GMT

Answer (score 24):

```
// you have time in utc
var dateUtc = DateTime.now().toUtc();
print("dateUtc: $dateUtc"); // 2019-10-10 12:05:01

// convert it to local
var dateLocal = dateUtc.toLocal();
print("local: $dateLocal"); // 2019-10-10 14:05:01
```

Can you see the difference in hours, in utc it is `12` and locally it is `14`.

Comment: this code returns same dates and hour. How can I check my locale?

Comment: @GiacomoM The code doesn't return same dates and hour, I showed the output in print format, you can see there is a time difference of GMT +2  (my local time zone).

Comment: I mean, I tried in my project and I get same hour :( I do not know why

Comment: @GiacomoM What's your time zone?

Comment: It is Europe/Rome

Comment: @GiacomoM I too have +2 time zone. Not sure why the code didn't work.

Comment: I get this: `dateUtc: 2020-08-10 13:44:25.982856Z`, `local: 2020-08-10 13:44:25.982856`. As you can see the Z disappeared, but the hours are the same

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect and simple.  toLocal()

Answer (score 13):

Two solutions I implemented

```
var date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").parse(json, true);
var dateLocal  = date.toLocal();
```

Other solutions add "Z"
You need to indicate a timezone to DateTime.parse, otherwise it assumes local time. From the dartdoc:

```
var date = DateTime.parse("${dateString}Z").toLocal();
var dateFormat = date2.toLocal();
```

Comment: That "Z" trick worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, convert your `Sting` to `DateTime`.

```
> DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(json['pickUpTime']);
```

Secondly, add `timeZoneOffSet` to your converted date time it will convert utc to your local time.

```
> dateTime = dateTime.add(DateTime.parse(json['pickUpTime']).timeZoneOffset);
```

Final Code

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(json['pickUpTime']);
dateTime = dateTime.add(DateTime.parse(json['pickUpTime']).timeZoneOffset);
```

Comment: all the advices with the DateFormat and toLocal or toUtc methods were not working for me. Yours did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
getNotificationDate(DateTime date) {
    date = DateTime.utc(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second);;
    final convertedDate = date.toLocal();

    final dateNow = DateTime.now();
    print('TIMENOW: ' + dateNow.toString());
    print('TIMENOTIFC: ' + convertedDate.toString());
    final difference = dateNow.difference(convertedDate);
    print('DIFFERENCE: ' + difference.toString());
    return getDurationFormat(difference);
  }
```

Comment: `time` was already in local, so what's the benefit of changing it to `utc` and then back to `local`?

Answer (score 3):

For those who parsing TimeStamp from Firestore.

*sentAt is Timestamp

```
String timeToDate = widget.sentAt.toDate().toString();
    var dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(timeToDate, true);
    var dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
```

Answer (score 3):

If somebody needs to parse a UTC timestamp in isoformat, for example something like this:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().format()
'2021-07-20T19:35:19.769891'
```

Then you can parse this and convert this to local time by

```dart
DateTime parseDatetimeFromUtc({required String isoFormattedString}){
  var dateTime = DateTime.parse(isoFormattedString + '+00:00');
  return dateTime.toLocal();
}
```

The `'+00:00'` is append here as the timezone information part which I do not send over my API to save some bytes. Maybe this helps someone who is in the same situation.

Of course you do not need this hardcoded suffix if you use a timezone aware timestamp in your backend:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2021-07-20T19:42:36.538195+00:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done something like this.

```
String dateTimeFormatter(String dateTime, {String? format}) {
  return DateFormat(format ?? 'yyyy/MM/dd, hh:mm a')
      .format(DateTime.parse(dateTime).toLocal())
      .toString();
}
```

just pass the format which you want to display in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several examples and forums, but it kept getting me the incorrect date time for my zone, The only way I made it work correctly was by using the GMT package

```
var nowLocal = DateTime.now();
print("toUtc: ${nowLocal.toUtc()}");
print("toLocalDateTime ${nowLocal.toLocalDateTime()}");
print("toLocal ${nowLocal.toLocal()}");
print("toIso8601String ${nowLocal.toIso8601String()}");
final timeZoneOffsetInHours = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inHours;
final nowGMT = await GMT.now();
print("GMT: $nowGMT");
final nowActual = nowGMT?.add(Duration(hours: timeZoneOffsetInHours));
print("nowActual $nowActual");
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/)

add following line :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

You can make an extension like below so it will be very helpful and easy to use anywhere in a whole project.

```
//just make sure you have passed the right date format of utc("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). I have passed by default my format.

//for example
// 2020-11-25 24:12:36 -> "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
DateTime localDate=utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime();


//for different formats you can pass your own dateFormat for utcDate like below:
// 20-11-25 24:12:36 -> "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
DateTime localDate=utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime toLocalDateTime({String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}) {
    var dateTime = DateFormat(format).parse(this.toString(), true);
    return dateTime.toLocal();
  }
}
```

Comment: this finally saved me.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i converted to my required time .which was showing as

```
I/flutter ( 5709): 16 Apr 08:30 PM 2021
```

when using the

```
var date=DateFormat("dd MMM hh:mm a y").format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(start*1000));
      print(date);
```

but after using this code i got my right time

```
var date=DateFormat("dd MMM hh:mm a y").format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(start*1000).toUtc());
      print(date);
```

which is

```
I/flutter ( 5709): 16 Apr 03:00 PM 2021
```

Answer (score -2):

convert utc number to DateTime:

```
  DateTime utcToDateTime(int utc) {
    return DateTime(1970, 1, 1).add(Duration(seconds: utc));
  }

  //test
  DateTime d = utcToDateTime(1649297709);
  print(d);
```