# How to display UTC time in local time

Tags: flutter, timezone, utc

In my flutter application I get appointment time in UTC format from a server.
I would like to display it in local time.

Is there a way to convert UTC to local time in flutter?

Comment: Link from elsewhere on SO;  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188960/680519
Hope this helps (I am totally new to Flutter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart has inbuilt DateTime type that provides quite a few handy methods to convert between time formats.

```
void main() {
  var utc = DateTime.parse("2020-06-11 17:47:35 Z");
  print(utc.toString());             // 2020-06-11 17:47:35.000Z
  print(utc.isUtc.toString());       // true
  print(utc.toLocal().toString());   //2020-06-11 23:17:35.000
}
```

Comment: I do not know `Dart` but I'm wondering if you really need to use `.toString()` in the print statement. In Java and similar languages, you can simply write `print(utc);` which will implicitly call `print(utc.toString());`

Comment: You don't need it. Since I'd initially typed it out with Text widget on flutter dartpad, I had to use the `.toString()` and I kept it as it is in the example posted too. But you can just as well do print(UTC) :)