# I want to convert utc time string to local time data - Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, timezone

I have an app and in that app I have to show chart but when I get chart data from backhand it form in UTC but my client is from San Francisco so he receive has invalid data because of different timezone

So I want to create a function that can change time according to user local time zone

How can I create that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime in UTC not converting to Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322185/datetime-in-utc-not-converting-to-local)

Comment: no because this question answers don't work for me

Comment: @Dipak If the `DateTime` object was constructed as UTC, then `.toLocal()` will convert it to the system's local time.  If *you* aren't using PST, then you will not see a PST time.  If it's still not working, you're probably not constructing the `DateTime` object properly and should show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use toLocal method. try below code

```
    var date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateUtc, true);
    var local = date.toLocal().toString();
    print(local);
```

Comment: this function is not working .tolocat function call DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch when time is not in utc

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that can change time according to user local time zone

```
void main() {
  var x = DateTime.now();
  print(x.year.toString() + "-" + padStart(x.month.toString()) + "-" + padStart(x.day.toString()));
}

String padStart(String str)
{
  return (str.length < 2) ? "0" + str: str;
}
```

[image: Expected output]

Comment: There's no need to write your own `pad` function. It's already included in `String`. See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/padLeft.html