# Date time convert in flutter Sun Dec 24 2023 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) format to yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm

Tags: flutter, dart, date, format

I need to convert this date format **Sun Dec 24 2023 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)** to **yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm** in flutter what is the actual date format Patten i can use for convert to custom date format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70765913/6280156

Comment: My question/issue regarding specific date format related can you please compare both questions

Answer (score 1):

Use DateFormat from `intl` package to format dates:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String dateString = "Sun Dec 24 2023 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)";

  /// Parsing the dateString to DateTime
  DateTime originalDate =
      DateFormat("EEE MMM dd y HH:mm:ss").parse(dateString);

  /// Getting the Formatted Date String 
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm').format(originalDate);

  print(formattedDate); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call function -> convertUniversalTimeToCustomFormat('Sun Dec 24 2023 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)')



 convertUniversalTimeToCustomFormat(String dateTime, {String currentDateFormat = 'EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz', String newDateFormat = 'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm'}) {
    var date = '';
    try {
      date = DateFormat(newDateFormat).format(DateTime.parse(DateFormat(currentDateFormat).parse(dateTime).toString()));
    } catch (e) {
      date = 'Invalid date';
    }
    return date;
  }
```